# lettter count is not repting in givinen input on javascript using -> document.elemetbyid

Tags: javascript, html, function, repeat

> check the error i give the input as a string and i want to output as a letter count. How many time letter is present in string?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function my() {
            var st = document.getElementById("j").value;
            var s = "l";

            var letter_Count = 0;
            for (var position = 0; position < st.length; position++) {
                if (st.charAt(position) == s) {
                    letter_Count += 1;
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = letter_Count;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <input type="text" name="j" id="j" onkeyup="my()" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `""` in `s`. This should work

```js
function my() {
  var st = document.getElementById("j").value;
  var s = "l";

  var letter_Count = 0;
  for (var position = 0; position < st.length; position++) {
    if (st.charAt(position) == "s") {
      letter_Count += 1;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = letter_Count;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<input type="text" name="j" id="j" onkeyup="my()" />
```

Comment: But the OP had `s` defined as `"l"`, so shouldn't it have worked as well (for the letter `l`)?

Comment: @CherryDT Thats a good catch! I thought OP wanted to count how many times a certain letter was typed (`s` in this case) so I removed the other variables. I somehow missed the `var s = "1"`